# Arrow function vs function keyword

Tags: javascript, function, arrow-functions

I have this arrow function that works just fine.

```
var sendData = (method, url, data, callback = null) => {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = callback;
    xhttp.open(method, url, true);
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
};
```

However if the callback is defined like this

```
sendDataDebugCallback = () => {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log('Hi');
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
};
```

it doesn't work, but if I use the function keyword it works

```
function sendDataDebugCallback() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log('Hi');
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
};
```

What are the diferences between those two types of function declaration? And why the arrow function doesn't work?

Comment: in these 2 cases the keyword `this` has different values

Comment: @MihaiT Yes, but why do they have different values?

Comment: The `this` keyword in the arrow function might be referring to the global scope. This blog might help 
https://dmitripavlutin.com/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/

Comment: In the arrow function, the this keyword refers to the windows, and in the other function it refers to the Xhttp object, why?

Comment: I meant that in the case of arrow functions `this` refers to the 'owner' of the function which might be a class or the window object etc. That's how arrow functions work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Because arrow functions don't have a context for `this`. They always refer to the enclosing object which in this case is the windows object. Functions declared with the `function` keyword have a context for this

Comment: And there is no way to pass the context to an arrow function?

Comment: No,and it shouldn't be. Arrow functions have their own purpose. Why not use 'normal' functions ?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation, I never used the function keyword, so I will need to investigate that, Thanks again!